# Filling XML data to DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have an XML of the following format. What is the best way to fill the data to Dataset?

```
<VariableTable>
    <InternalName Old="sujith" New="sujitha" /> 
    <InternalName Old="renjith" New="renjitha" /> 
</VariableTable>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dataset.ReadXML()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx)  method, you can use it , and also check for this links [Reading xml in Dataset](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2008/03/27/how-to-read-xml-data-into-a-dataset.aspx)

there are many options.

1. Give your xml File path, then load it to dataset
2. using XmlTextReader, pass it to the Dataset readxml method

> ```
> string xmlFilename = "XmlFilePath.xml";
>          DataSet yourDataset = new DataSet();
>          yourDataset.ReadXml(xmlFilename);
>          // do with your filled Dataset
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the XML a little bit, then DataSets provide built in functionality to load and save data to/from xml.

You could then use methods
    WriteXml()
    ReadXml()

If you need to load custom xml file format, then you need to write the code to parse it and populate dataset. For that you could use Linq or XPath.

Hope that helps.

**UPDATED**

```
    var dataSet = new DataSet("TestDataSet");
    var dataTable = new DataTable("TestTable");

    dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

    dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Value1");
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

    dataSet.WriteXml(@"L:\ds.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

the above code is what I used with WriteToXml method.
No this is the output XML format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<TestDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="TestDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="TestDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="TestTable">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <TestTable>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Value>Value1</Value>
  </TestTable>
</TestDataSet>
```

That's how the data would be stored in XML...

It might be a bit of an overhead if you need something simple, but this is the functionality out of the box.

Does that give you an idea how to do it?

Comment: What modification should I make to the xml?

Comment: Check the updated post to see the xml format you need. That includes XML schema.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function FillDataSetFromXML(ByVal Procedure As String, ByVal param As List(Of SqlParameter)) As DataSet
    Dim dbcon As New dbConnection()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim XR As XmlReader
    XR = Nothing
    Try
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = Procedure
        dbcon.OpenConnection()
        cmd.Connection = dbcon.GetDbConnection()
        If param.Count > 0 Then
            For Each p As SqlParameter In param
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value)
            Next
        End If
        XR = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader()
        ds.ReadXml(XR)
        Return ds
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ds
    Finally
        dbcon.CloseConnection()
    End Try

End Function

Public Function ExecuteScalar(ByVal Qry As String)
    Dim dbcon As New dbConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim res As String
    Try
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = Qry
        dbcon.OpenConnection()
        cmd.Connection = dbcon.GetDbConnection()
        res = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
        Return res

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return res
    Finally
        dbcon.CloseConnection()
    End Try       
End Function

Public Function ExecuteProdedures(ByVal param As List(Of SqlParameter), ByVal Procedure As String) As DataSet

    Dim dbcon As New dbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = Procedure
        dbcon.OpenConnection()
        cmd.Connection = dbcon.GetDbConnection()
        If param.Count > 0 Then
            For Each p As SqlParameter In param
                'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p.ParameterName, p.Value)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
            Next
        End If
        Dim XR As XmlReader
        XR = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader()
        ds.ReadXml(XR)
        Return ds
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        dbcon.CloseConnection()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: A giant wall of code with no explanation is rarely is very good or useful answer. Especially on 3 year old questions with already accepted answers.